# Batch file rename basing on a look up table

Tags: r

Hello, all

I'm pretty new to R and I wish to accomplish the following task

I have many files need to do this task. I simplify the situation to five 
files. Their names are

```
001 
232 
242 
123 
132
```

I'd like to change the name of each file (column 1) to the name in column 2 
in the following table

```
column1    column2 
001            ewr 
232            eda 
242            gdg 
123            sgs 
132            ger
```

I'm wondering if anyone could point out a way to do it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: look at `?file.rename`, or the first google result for 'renaming files with R'....

Answer (score 1):

assume your data.frame is

```
df<-data.frame(a=c("001","232","242","123","132"),b=c("ewr","eda","gdg","sgs","ger"))
```

you can use

```
apply(df,1,function(x){file.rename(x[1],x[2])})
```

Answer (score 0):

Or as simple as...

`with(df, file.rename(a,b))`